# MongoDB, Express + GraphQL server: Updated data model with new fields, but queries do not pick up new fields

Tags: mongodb, express, graphql, mongoose-schema, express-graphql

I created a GraphQL server in combination with Express + MongoDB. I started with the following data model:

```
const AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  age: { type: Number, required: true },
});
```

Queries + Mutations are working, but I decided to add more fields to the data model:

```
const AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  age: { type: Number, required: true },
  bio: { type: String, required: true },
  picture: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

I can add a new author through a mutation with the new fields, but for some reason, queries will not return the new fields.

````
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"bio\" on type \"Author\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GraphQL types are not the same as your Mongoose schemas. If you add a field to `AuthorSchema` schema and want to also expose this as a field on your `Author` type, then you need to explicitly define the field in your GraphQL schema.